# javascript Regex with alias

Tags: javascript, regex

I am very new to regex. I wanted to search for names and create an alias.
example if ABCDEF has an alias QWERTY.
So if someone types in ABCDEF -> the output should have ABCDEF and QWERTY.
I did this with an IF condition on the output variable, and i get the match.

However I am doing this to filter result sets, and I have called a loop in which each entry as executed filters the results. So how do i do a chaining?

So, my inputs and outputs are as follows :

when i type A -> ABCDEF, 
when AB -> ABCDEG, ...

Now what I want is when i type say Q, i want the result set to have ABCDEF as well, since QWERTY is an equivalent of ABCDEF.

How do I achieve this on the alias?
How do I go about this?

I am sorry, but I am really new to regex. So, very confused, even in asking.
What I think, is something near something else.
Say, for example if i search for "alter", i should get "change" in the result set, if i could hand code it.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. What do you mean by chaining? Could you show a before-after sample of what you want to achieve and where your current method is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `exec` and `concat` methods to return the search string along with the match:

```
var foo = RegExp("ABCDEF").exec("ABCDEF").concat(" QWERTY")
var bar = RegExp("Q").exec("Q").concat(" ABCDEF");
```